# TypeScript Removing Repetitive Property Assignment with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am using TS React Redux and my app state looks something like this

```
type AppState = {
   foo: number
   bar: number
   baz: number
}
```

and I have a component whose hooked up to redux like so

```
type ComponentState = {
   foo: number
   bar: number
}

function mapStateToProps(state: AppState): ComponentState{
   return {
      foo: state.foo,
      bar: state.bar
   }
}
```

My question is that in `mapStateToProps`, is there any way to copy over the props without having to select each one individually? Since `ComponentState` is a subset of `AppState` I feel like there is an obvious way to do this that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `connect` and TypeScript together, we specifically recommend using [the `ConnectedProps<T>` pattern](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically) to infer the type of all the props passed from `connect` to your component.  That will eliminate the need to write that `ComponentState` interface if you don't want to, as TS will also infer the return type of `mapState`.

You should also consider using [our `useSelector` hook in function components](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks), as it's easier to type than `connect` is.

Comment: Thanks! I think that is closest to what I'm looking for. Still have to iterate over certain properties, but ```ConnectedProps``` gets rid of half.

Answer (score 0):

you can destructure the items you want to use, however a `mapStateToProps` function is the place where you define what to take out of the state to give to the component.

```
function mapStateToProps({foo, bar}: AppState): ComponentState {
   return { foo, bar }
}
```

if you were wanting to do a more functional approach you could do something like this

```
const myComponentKeys: Array<keyof ComponentState> = ['foo', 'bar']
function mapStateToProps(state: AppState): ComponentState {
   return pick(myComponentKeys, state)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!